# Inserting multiple rows in the JOOQ + returning the ids

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

I am working on a Spring Boot application where I am using JOOQ version 3.15.5 to communicate with the DB. Now I am trying to insert multiple rows in DB and to get the IDs as the result set. How can I do this? I tried to use `valuesOfRecords` to insert a collection of records but I couldn't make it work, because it forces me to put all the fields of MY_TABLE, including the unknown ID. I tried:

```
context
   .insertInto(MY_TABLE, MY_TABLE.ID, MY_TABLE.STATUS, MY_TABLE.NAME)
   .valuesOfRecords(records)
   .returningResult(MY_TABLE.ID)
   .fetchInto(Long.class);
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you're using updatable records, you should perhaps be able to just batch-store the records, then get the generated IDs? First this: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.15/manual-single-page/#batch-execution-for-crud, then just call `getId()` on the stored records, as seen here: https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.15/manual-single-page/#simple-crud

Comment: Also, this issue specifically talks about your approach: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12270 and how to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solving the problem at hand

You don't *have to* include the `ID` column. Why not just write this instead?

```java
context

   // No ID column here
   .insertInto(MY_TABLE, MY_TABLE.STATUS, MY_TABLE.NAME)

   // Use a Record2<?, ?> type here
   .valuesOfRecords(records)
   .returningResult(MY_TABLE.ID)
   .fetchInto(Long.class);
```

If your records are the generated `MyTableRecord` which you configured to extend `Record3<?, ?, ?>`, you'll just have to map the desired content to a `Record2<?, ?>`, or even to a `Row2<?, ?>`:

```java
context
   .insertInto(MY_TABLE, MY_TABLE.STATUS, MY_TABLE.NAME)
   .valuesOfRows(records
       .stream()
       // An example mapping. 
       .map(r -> row(r.getStatus(), r.getName()))
       .toList()
    )
   .returningResult(MY_TABLE.ID)
   .fetchInto(Long.class);
```

The jOOQ 3.15 [`org.jooq.Rows`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Rows.html) utility has a few mapping functions that help with such cases. You could even write:

```java
context
   .insertInto(MY_TABLE, MY_TABLE.STATUS, MY_TABLE.NAME)
   .valuesOfRows(records
       .stream()
       .collect(Rows.toRowList(r -> r.getStatus(), r -> r.getName()))
    )
   .returningResult(MY_TABLE.ID)
   .fetchInto(Long.class);
```

#### Using 3.16 readonly columns

Starting from jOOQ 3.16, there is support for readonly columns:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/9864
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/readonly-columns/

If jOOQ knows your `ID` column is readonly (and it is, if it's an identity column), then it will ignore it from such statement if you configure it accordingly.